# Vagrant xdebug on Arch Linux

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I recently switched from Ubuntu 18.04 to Arch based Manjaro Linux. Since that day my Vagrant project rejects xdebug connections. The vagrant config did not change only the host operating system.

The vagrant box is a Ubuntu 18.04, created with this Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |jinya|
  jinya.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
  jinya.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
    virtualbox.name = "jinya"
    virtualbox.cpus = 2
    virtualbox.memory = 2048
  end

  jinya.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.10"
  jinya.vm.synced_folder ".", "/jinya"
  jinya.vm.provision "shell", path: "./vagrant-files/provision.sh", keep_color: true
end
```

The provisiong script installs the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2 php7.2-json php7.2-xml php7.2-fpm php7.2-mysql php7.2-zip php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-opcache php7.2-curl php7.2-intl php7.2-mbstring php-xdebug apache2 libapache2-mod-php
```

Apart from the automatic installs I also compile tideways and include it into my stack.

```
sudo apt install -y php7.2-dev make
git clone https://github.com/tideways/php-profiler-extension.git
cd php-profiler-extension
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
echo "extension=tideways_xhprof.so" | sudo tee /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/tideways_xhprof.ini
sudo phpenmod tideways_xhprof
```

The config for xdebug looks like this:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

The file `/tmp/xdebug.log` stays empty and I don't get a debug connection in PhpStorm.

The PhpStorm config didn't change either, here is the current setting:

[image: PhpStorm config]

Comment: 1) Enable "phone handle" in PhpStorm, SSH into your VM and try to connect from there to PhpStorm on Xdebug port (e.g. using telnet) -- you will see if it's possible or not (maybe some firewall etc). 2) Ensure that correct php.ini is used (you may have more than one setup etc) 3) Any SELinux or alike (that may prevent Apache from making outgoing connections and Xdebug will not fire)

Comment: Well it was a very simple firewall issue. Manjaro seems to be more restrictive than Ubuntu. Apparently I tried the wrong rules... So with the correct ports openend it works like a charm, thank you a lot. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.